# How can I render dynamic HTML in component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following Ember handlebar template and I want to render it to DOM dynamically including with the onclick event listener. How to do it in EmberJS?

**hello.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        var message = `
            <p>Hello World!</p>
            <a onclick={{action "handleOpenUrl"}}>Learn More</a>
        `;
        this.set('message', message);
    },

    actions: {
        handleOpenUrl() {
            //open url code
        }
    }
});
```

**hello.hbs**

```
{{{message}}}
```

**Expected output in DOM**

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
<a>Learn More</a>
```

And when I click on Learn More, `handleOpenUrl` should be called

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Looks like you try to bypass glimmer, ember's template engine.

Comment: I am trying to render Ember handlebar template (with onclick actions) to DOM dynamically on Component startup

Comment: @jelhan Just edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Your thinking about it all wrong, this is not how ember works. Your HTML should be in your `template.hbs` not your js file.

Comment: Although this isn’t a standard Ember approach, it shouldn’t be written off as completely wrong, as there are cases where it is needed. I’ve outlined how to handle it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711436/334913

Answer (score 2):

You should have something more like this:

### hello.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   showMessage:false,
   actions: {
        handleOpenUrl() {
            //open url code
        }
    }
});
```

### hello.hbs

```
{{#if showMessage}}
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <a {{action "handleOpenUrl"}}>Learn More</a>
{{/if}}
```

you then toggle `showMessage` to hide or show your HTML. Your action declaration is also wrong (I've corrected above), see https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/actions/

you then consume the component in your main route:

```
{{hello showMessage=true}}
```

If you want to render different HTML then you'll need to use `yield`:

```
{{#if showMessage}}
   {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

this will allow you to consume your component this way:

```
{{#hello showMessage=true}}
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <a {{action "handleOpenUrl"}}>Learn More</a>
{{/hello}}
```

Your `action` **now doesn't live in the component**. You'll need the action to be in **controller** now. TBH I don't see the point in using a component if you want to do this. Just use a standard `{{#if}}`

It seems that your just trying ot reuse the `onclick` action. If this is the case then a [mixin](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Mixin) or a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.6.0/applications/services/) is the way to go not a component.

Comment: My message will be changing and is dynamic. In other places, I will be showing some other message or different link (probably a different template with `h1` tag, etc). In that case, what could be the solution?

Comment: Is there anything I could dynamically render `{{hello showMessage=true}}` from JS?

Comment: Why are you using a component here at all? Components are for rendering common features. If there is nothing common the component becomes a waste of time

Answer (score 1):

First your question is wrong: You don't ask if you can render dynamic HTML but if you can render dynamic *handlebars*! Short answer: no.

Long answer:

Your primary misunderstanding is probably that you think ember is at some point rendering handlebars strings in the browser. It is not!
Ember compiles the handlebars to glimmer VM byte code during compile time. The handlebars compiler or the handlebars template will never be sent to the browser. So there is nothing to parse handlebars.

What you want is probably easily achievable but this is a classic X/Y problem situation.

Also be aware that rendering HTML (which is possible) is a security risk. I would recommend you to ask a new question about how to do what you actually want, without focusing on a specific way to solve your problem.