# Bind html string in controller to template does not trigger click event

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a html string in controller and I bind this to view, but the action does not trigger on clicking.

I already applied the `triple braces` or `htmlSafe` to avoid html escape, the button shows on the template but when clicking on it does not trigger action `newAlert`

```
## hello.js

import { htmlSafe } from '@ember/string';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  htmlString: computed(function() {
    return htmlSafe('<button {{action "newAlert"}}>Test Alert</button>')
  }),
  actions: {
    newAlert: function(){
      alert('Hello')
    }
  }
});
```

```
## hello.hbs

{{htmlString}}
```

Could you guys help me shows what is going wrong?

Comment: What you are trying doesn't look like the ember-way. It seems that you are running in the wrong direction. What are you trying to achieve? What's your use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I render dynamic HTML in component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034794/how-can-i-render-dynamic-html-in-component)

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034794/how-can-i-render-dynamic-html-in-component), try to make a new question with what you actually want to do or checkout the ember discord chat to discuss this

Comment: I received a html string from the server and I want to display it on the view, this is the button and then when I click on the button, it will trigger an actions to do something. Just make a sort code for you guys easy to get my point.

Comment: The point is: This is **not HTML**! Its uncompiled handlebars. Have you read my answer on the other question? Maybe you wanna join the official community [Discord server](https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS). There are usually nice people in the help channel to discuss things like this.

Comment: yeah thank Lux, I got your point.

Comment: if you know tho that in that html is exactly one button just manually append the `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, there can be real security problems introduced by using raw HTML from the server. That said, there are times that is indeed needed and you may want that raw HTML to work with Ember’s event system.

The simplest way to do this is to render the raw HTML inside of a component. In the component, also add a `click` method to the main component body. Doing so gives you the ability to intercept raw DOM events instead of working within the actions system that Handlebars enables.

Most of the time it is simplest to live in a Handlebars world, but at times you need to get back to raw JS events.

More details on the guides here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/